# Trying to schedule AWS lambda function with cron expression

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to run the AWS lambda function every day at 23:59 hours. I am trying to setup cloudwatch event apply the cron expression cron(59 23 * * ? *), but getting an error:

Error
There was an error while saving rule Athene-Lambda-error-logs.
Details: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid..

Can someone confirm is the expression is correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, could you provide more steps to reproduce? Are you doing this via CLI, console or IAC?

Comment: I'm trying on the console. Please find the attached screenshot.

Comment: Just omit cron and the brackets: 59 23 * * ? *